# how to set download link into laravel site.com => dl.site.com

Tags: laravel

i define download link and work! But now I want my download link from this "site.com" to "dl.site.com", because I just bought a download host and the previous links have failed,So I bought a space for the Laraveli project and a download host. Thank you this my route

```
Route::get('dl/course/{id}/{slug}', [DownloadsController::class, 'downloadDemo'])->name('front.download.demo')->middleware('signed');
```

and this download link

```
https://example.com/dl/course/13/mvc?expires=1638040581&signature=9e2e4f304b2c8a1c79bffb0a3cd439bd2294c4be358ef993dbf54e6ceed434ba
```

i want now this download link

```
https://dl.example.com/dl/course/13/mvc?expires=1638040581&signature=9e2e4f304b2c8a1c79bffb0a3cd439bd2294c4be358ef993dbf54e6ceed434ba
```

Comment: Show your controller code, that generates this links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Route::domain('dl.example.com')->middleware('signed')->group(function(){
    Route::get('dl/course/{id}/{slug}', [DownloadsController::class, 'downloadDemo'])->name('front.download.demo');
});
```

Comment: no, give me error 404 when run this route

Comment: try now, I'v made a typo